# Implementing a DDEX provider for exposing PostgreSQL data source objects in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, postgresql

I started implementing a DDEX provider for PostgreSQL in Visual Studio 2010. First of all, I've downloaded from [EFSampleProvider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFSampleProvider), where it contains the basics to begin. I' ve also downloaded the src of Npgsql 2.0.10 from [here](http://pgfoundry.org/frs/?group_id=1000140) which contains a VisualStudio folder where there are 4 basic files (but not much in there). Those files are the ones that are needed to be filled with the appropriate code.

Though, I familiarized myself to the basic principles of a DDEX architecture, I lack of any knowledge on Postgres and especially over the data objects (and their properties, parameters, etc) that I need to continue.

Does anyone have an idea where can I look up for these?

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Npgsql API documentation](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/api/index.html) can help.

Comment: unfortunately this project was abandoned. Nevertheless thank you for your reply and I ll keep it in mind whenever I return back to this.